# How to cache part of the page only

Tags: php, caching

I need a code to cache just part of the page, in fact i want to cache the result of a function.

**Example :**

```
CODE HTML

<? my php code ?> <!- I want to cache this only -->

CODE HTML
```

I found a few incomplete codes but functions are missing and it's not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean server-side caching for a function that takes awhile to run but has the same output for many users.

If so, check out Memcached.  http://memcached.org/

http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Hash the parameters for your function, use that as a key.  Then stick the result in memcached and check for it the next time that function is called.